# Is Imagenet_1k dataset enough to train Resnet50 model?

Tags: pytorch, resnet

I used nervana distiller to train resnet50 baseline model with imagenet_1k dataset.I've observed after 100 epochs, Top5 accuracy is about 10%.The validation accuracy remains zero for long step.

Comment: what were your expectations?

Comment: I want to explore the loss of accuracy when quantizing resnet50 model on imagenet with INT4 config